# Change cursor on Dialog Dragging

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I know there are at least two ways of doing this: Javascript and C#. I would like to do it C#. So I have found an example to perform Dialog dragging C# way. However I would like to change the cursor while dragging. How it can be achieved?

EmployeesBase.cs:

```
protected double startX, startY, offsetX, offsetY;

public EmployeesBase()
{
  this.employee = new Data.Employee();
  this.offsetY = 100;
}

protected void OnDragStart(DragEventArgs args)
{
  startX = args.ClientX;
  startY = args.ClientY;
}

protected void OnDragEnd(DragEventArgs args)
{
  offsetX += args.ClientX - startX;
  offsetY += args.ClientY - startY;
}
```

Employees.razor:

```
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; background-color: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.4); ">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" draggable="true"
     @ondragend="OnDragEnd" @ondragstart="OnDragStart"
     style="position:absolute; top: @(offsetY)px; left: @(offsetX)px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Add new record</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="ClosePopup">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <EditForm Model="employees" OnValidSubmit="SubmitForm">
        </EditForm>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I did some research and.. well - this one is tough to beat. Even solutions with js/html/css doesn't work consistent... If you can do it with js, I will be ready to help you with blazor implementation. But it seams like some deeper magic is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to avoid the drag and drop method and code it using mouse events

```cs
protected double startX, startY, offsetX, offsetY=100;
protected string cursor="pointer";
protected bool isDragging=false;

protected void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs args)
{
  startX = args.PageX;
  startY = args.PageY;
  cursor="grab";
  isDragging = true;
}

protected void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs args)
{
  if (isDragging)
  {
    offsetX += args.PageX - startX;
    offsetY += args.PageY - startY;
    startX = args.PageX;
    startY = args.PageY;
  }
}
protected void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs args)
{
    isDragging = false;
    cursor="pointer";
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; background-color: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.4); " 
    @onmousemove="OnMouseMove">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" 
        @onmouseup="OnMouseUp" @onmousedown="OnMouseDown" 
        style="position:absolute; top: @(offsetY)px; left: @(offsetX)px;cursor:@cursor;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add new record</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We have the `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` on the element we want to move and the `onmousemove` on the background element. We can then use CSS to change the cursor while "dragging".

Try it out: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/wvPvmuYo40iNCUkS45

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works! Can you give me a hint, how to make it so that dragging would not take effect then cursor is inside textboxes?

Comment: Initial thought is - only apply the onmousedown, onmouseup to a header bar in the dialog, rather than the whole dialog?